# AttributeError: 'QgsVectorLayer' object has no attribute 'fieldNameIndex'

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, fields-attributes, attributeerror, qgsvectorlayer

When I try to calculate a new field with:

```py
idx = layer.fieldNameIndex(attributeName)
```

I receive the following error:

> AttributeError: 'QgsVectorLayer' object has no attribute 'fieldNameIndex'

What´s the problem? I'm using QGIS 3.0.1 64x in Windows.

Comment: Please, do not forget about ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

### In PyQGIS 3

Use one of the following methods from the [`QgsFields`](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsFields.html) class:

1. [`indexFromName()`](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsFields.html#a4d243eff35b31845588ebdce08322b44)

   ```py
   layer = iface.activeLayer()
   layer_fields = layer.fields()
   field_index = layer_fields.indexFromName("FIELD_NAME")
   ```
2. [`lookupField()`](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsFields.html#ae10bb68f955914e5056eb36b5089f4d1):

   ```py
   layer = iface.activeLayer()
   layer_fields = layer.fields()
   field_index = layer_fields.lookupField("FIELD_NAME")
   ```
3. [`indexOf()`](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsFields.html#a6b0f588bd6d2f71241c8795293c36f20)

   ```py
   layer = iface.activeLayer()
   layer_fields = layer.fields()
   field_index = layer_fields.indexOf("FIELD_NAME")
   ```

Answer (score 7):

You need to access it via the [`fieldNameIndex()`](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorDataProvider.html#a8af47d0fa09374a7cb39abacb8a328e6) method of the [`QgsVectorDataProvider`](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorDataProvider.html) class:

```py
layer = iface.activeLayer()
idx = layer.dataProvider().fieldNameIndex(attributeName)
```

Comment: How do you do that in the Python console? I'm a noob.

Comment: @MarcoUscuchagua - Click on a layer and type `layer = iface.activeLayer()`. Then type `idx = layer.dataProvider().fieldNameIndex("fieldName"). The `self` parameter is mainly used for plugins.

Comment: The error remains. I think it is a error of QGIS and not of my layer.

Comment: @MarcoUscuchagua - What error are you receiving? Is it the same error as in your question?

Comment: Yes! The exactly error: [image](https://ibb.co/n0BBxS)

Comment: @MarcoUscuchagua - If you're using the **Python Console**, do not use `self`.

Comment: I found the solution!! The problem was in the [Quick Attribution](https://github.com/opengisch/quick_attribution) plugin, its reinstallation solved the problem. Thanks @Joseph

Comment: @MarcoUscuchagua - Glad you found a solution :)