# Getting field index from input vector layer in PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, fields-attributes, indexing

I am currently trying to convert a python script from QGIS 2.18 to QGIS 3. Therefore, I am trying to integrate my python script into the template from @underdark: [see here](https://anitagraser.com/2018/03/25/processing-script-template-for-qgis3/).

I am currently stepping from one error into another so I seek help as I was not able to find any other question on Stack Exchange or any documentation.

Here is some part of my script so far:

```py
def processAlgorithm(self, parameters, context, feedback):
    inEdges = self.parameterAsVectorLayer(parameters, self.INPUT_VECTOR_LAYER_EDGES, context)
    inNodes = self.parameterAsVectorLayer(parameters, self.INPUT_VECTOR_LAYER_NODES, context)
    outMerged = self.parameterAsOutputLayer(parameters, self.OUTPUT_VECTOR_LAYER_MERGED, context)

    #DO SOME CALCULATION
    
    # get field indices for inputlayer
    idxEdgeId = inEdges.fieldNameIndex(ID)
    idxPriority = inEdges.fieldNameIndex(PRIORITY)
    idxLength  = inEdges.fieldNameIndex(LENGTH)
    idxTime    = inEdges.fieldNameIndex(TIME)
    idxFrom  = inEdges.fieldNameIndex(FROM)
    idxTo  = inEdges.fieldNameIndex(TO)

    idx_id = inNodes.fieldNameIndex(NODEID)
    idx_x = inNodes.fieldNameIndex(COORD_X)
    idx_y = inNodes.fieldNameIndex(COORD_Y)

    # Set the provider to accept the data source
    outdp = outMerged.dataProvider()

    # define attributes and add them to the vector layer
    outdp.addAttributes([QgsField(EDGEID, QVariant.String),
                        QgsField(NODE1, QVariant.String),
                        QgsField(NODE2, QVariant.String),
                        QgsField(PRIORITY, QVariant.Int),
                        QgsField(VTO, QVariant.Double),
                        QgsField(VFROM, QVariant.Double)])
    outMerged.updateFields()

    # get field indices for outputlayer
    outEdgeId = outdp.fieldNameIndex(EDGEID)
    outNode1 = outdp.fieldNameIndex(NODE1)
    outNode2 = outdp.fieldNameIndex(NODE2)
    outPriority = outdp.fieldNameIndex(PRIORITY)
    outVTo = outdp.fieldNameIndex(VTO)
    outVFrom = outdp.fieldNameIndex(VFROM)

    listOfEdgeIds = []
    count = 0
    flag = 0

    (...)
```

For your information: I have two input vector layers (one point, and one line layer) and out of that, I want to create one outputlayer (which should be a line-vector layer as well).

But currently I have trouble with the `fieldNameIndex(QString)` - method in the first section of the code. I have already tried to call the method with the `dataProvider()` of the input layer, but that hasn't worked out. I get error:

> Traceback (most recent call last): File
> "C:\Users\tlichten\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\processing\scripts\merging.py",
> line 89, in processAlgorithm idxEdgeId = inEdges.fieldNameIndex(ID)
> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'fieldNameIndex'

Although I have to input vector layers, I cannot select any of them if I want to start the script. The execute script window looks like this:

[image]

In QGIS2.18, there would be two drop-down menus in which to choose between the input layers.

I have adapted the `initAlgorithm()` to the following:

```py
    def initAlgorithm(self, config=None):
    self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterVectorLayer(
        self.INPUT_VECTOR_LAYER_EDGES, 
        self.tr('Edges'),
        [QgsProcessing.TypeVectorAnyGeometry]))
    self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterRasterLayer(
        self.INPUT_VECTOR_LAYER_NODES,
        self.tr('Nodes')
        [QgsProcessing.TypeVectorAnyGeometry]))
    self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterRasterDestination(
        self.OUTPUT_VECTOR_LAYER_MERGED,
        self.tr("Output Vector Layer Merged"),
        [QgsProcessing.TypeVectorAnyGeometry]))
```

But I can still not select any input layers if I execute the script.

Comment: I have shortened the code segment. The error message I receive when trying to execute the script is as follows: Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Users\tlichten\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\processing\scripts\merging.py", line 89, in processAlgorithm idxEdgeId = inEdges.fieldNameIndex(ID) AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'fieldNameIndex'

Comment: I have edited my question. Please see above. How do I select the layer in the input field. If I run the script from the toolbox I cannot select any inputlayer as it was with QGIS 2.18. I can just press start...

Comment: Your code snippet is different than the sourced example you reference.  That one uses a class which gets the parameters.

Comment: in initAlgorithm() function

Comment: yea I have already updated it. But it still does not work .

Comment: You can't mix "Raster" and "Vector" in one parameter definition (your INPUT_VECTOR_LAYER_NODES name suggest it should be a vector not a raster) . Do you need Raster input or output?
For output you should call self.addOutput.

Comment: **Related topic:** https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/279934/attributeerror-qgsvectorlayer-object-has-no-attribute-fieldnameindex

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That method has been deprecated, use this instead to get the field index:

```
fields = inEdges.fields()
idxEdgeId = fields.indexFromName('fieldName')
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, I have tried your solution, but it looks like the fields() method is not known. This is my error now: Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Users\tlichten\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\processing\scripts\merging.py", line 89, in processAlgorithm fields = inEdges.fields() AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'fields'

Comment: How/where is the processAlgorithm() being called?  The vector layer "inEdges" is not valid.

Comment: I have edited the question. Please have a look! Thank you so much

Comment: is the newFeature.setAttribute() method deprecated as well?? How can I set an attribute of a new feature for the output layer?

Comment: That method should still work.  The referenced blog you noted in your question shows how to do that.  Also, that question is different from this question so you should post a new question about that.

Answer (score 6):

fieldNameIndex function was removed in QGIS3:

> Removed fieldNameIndex(), use fields().lookupField() or
>   fields().indexFromName() instead

You can convert your code as follows:

```
inEdges = self.parameterAsVectorLayer(parameters, self.INPUT_VECTOR_LAYER_EDGES, context)
inEdgesFields = inEdges.fields()

idxEdgeId = inEdgesFields.indexFromName(ID)
```

For more details see https://qgis.org/api/api_break.html

---

Exception you've got, suggest that you have problem with parameters, make sure you add parameters with proper key in initAlgorithm function (in QGIS2 it was defineCharacteristics):

```
def initAlgorithm(self, config=None):
    self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterVectorLayer(self.INPUT_VECTOR_LAYER_EDGES, self.tr('Edges'), types=[QgsProcessing.TypeVector]))
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, I have tried your solution, but it looks like the fields() method is not known. This is my error now: Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Users\tlichten\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\processing\scripts\merging.py", line 90, in processAlgorithm inEdgesFields = inEdges.fields() AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'fields'

Comment: Make sure the parameters are properly added in initAlgorithm(self, config=None) function and you select valid layer in the input field

Comment: the initAlgorithm method should work properly. But how do I select the layer in the input field. If I run the script from the toolbox I cannot select any inputlayer as it was with QGIS 2.18. I can just press start...

Comment: I have edited my question. Please have a look for better understanding :)

Comment: See my edited answer

Comment: I have edited the question. Please have a look.

Comment: is the newFeature.setAttribute() method deprecated as well?? How can I set an attribute of a new feature for the output layer?

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, there is also a possibility of using the [`indexOf(fieldName: str)`](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsFields.html#a6b0f588bd6d2f71241c8795293c36f20) method.

```py
from qgis.utils import iface

layer = iface.activeLayer()

fields = layer.fields()

fields_indxs = [fields.indexOf(field.name()) for field in fields]
```