# Getting only joined fields using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, fields-attributes, attribute-joins, vector-layer

How do I get a list of fields that have been joined to a layer, or how can I check if a specific field has been joined?

In older versions there seemed to be `field.source()`, but this is not available anymore.

I am **not** performing the join via PyQGIS. The join is done manually and I would just like to use PyQGIS to detect which fields have been joined.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One can detect which fields have been joined by means of the `QgsFields` class and its method [`fieldOrigin`](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsFields.html#a8c12cf0b2579a951c4b43a3aa363075e):

> Returns the field's origin (value from an enumeration).

```py
from qgis.core import QgsProject

layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("points")[0]

joined_fields = []

if len(layer.vectorJoins()) > 0:
       
    fields = layer.fields()
            
    for field in fields:
        field_name = field.name()
        indx = fields.indexOf(field_name)
        
        if fields.fieldOrigin(indx) == fields.OriginJoin:
        # or if fields.fieldOrigin(indx) == 2:
            joined_fields.append(field_name)
            
print(joined_fields)
```

The above code will result in a list of fields that have been joined to a layer. In my case it will be:

```
['month', 'month2', 'month3']
```

[`2 = OriginJoin`](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsFields.html#a73485dec1797ca263d3319d9dc10e903) means that this field comes from a joined layer.

> `OriginJoin`   Field comes from a joined layer (originIndex / 1000 =
> index of the join, originIndex % 1000 = index within the join)

---

**References:**

- [Getting field names of layer using PyQGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/347126/getting-field-names-of-layer-using-pyqgis)
- [Getting field index from input vector layer in PyQGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/303928/getting-field-index-from-input-vector-layer-in-pyqgis)

Comment: Works very well. Thank you for providing a very clear answer!