# Updating length in an existing field using PyQGIS - changes not persisting

Tags: python, pyqgis-3

I have a group of layers and I want to edit the field in some of them. More specifically, I want to change the length in those fields named `ATTRIBUTE1`. I'm using this code

```py
from qgis import core
from qgis.core import QgsApplication
from qgis.core.additions.edit import edit
from qgis.core import QgsProject


# Get the project instance
project = QgsProject.instance()

# load layer tree
root = project.instance().layerTreeRoot()

# extract group
wip_layer = root.findGroup("Layers").findGroup("wip_equipaments_polygons")

# get all layers in the group
layers = [c.layer() for c in wip_layer.children()]

field_of_interest = "ATTRIBUTE1"



for layer in layers:
    layer: core.QgsVectorLayer
    with edit(layer):
        for field in layer.fields():
            field: core.QgsField
            if field.typeName() == "String":
                if field.name() == field_of_interest:
                    print("field found")
                    print("before", field.name(), field.length(), end="->")
                    field.setLength(50)
                    print("after", field.name(), field.length())
                    layer.updateFields()
```

I'm getting this result

```
field found
before ATTRIBUTE1 8->after ATTRIBUTE1 50
field found
before ATTRIBUTE1 8->after ATTRIBUTE1 50
field found
before ATTRIBUTE1 8->after ATTRIBUTE1 50
field found
before ATTRIBUTE1 8->after ATTRIBUTE1 50
field found
before ATTRIBUTE1 8->after ATTRIBUTE1 50
field found
before ATTRIBUTE1 8->after ATTRIBUTE1 50
field found
before ATTRIBUTE1 8->after ATTRIBUTE1 50
field found
before ATTRIBUTE1 8->after ATTRIBUTE1 50
field found
before ATTRIBUTE1 8->after ATTRIBUTE1 50
field found
before ATTRIBUTE1 50->after ATTRIBUTE1 50
field found
before ATTRIBUTE1 50->after ATTRIBUTE1 50
field found
before ATTRIBUTE1 50->after ATTRIBUTE1 50
field found
before ATTRIBUTE1 50->after ATTRIBUTE1 50
field found
before ATTRIBUTE1 50->after ATTRIBUTE1 50
field found
before ATTRIBUTE1 50->after ATTRIBUTE1 50
field found
before ATTRIBUTE1 50->after ATTRIBUTE1 50
field found
before ATTRIBUTE1 50->after ATTRIBUTE1 50
field found
before ATTRIBUTE1 50->after ATTRIBUTE1 50
field found
before ATTRIBUTE1 50->after ATTRIBUTE1 50
field found
before ATTRIBUTE1 50->after ATTRIBUTE1 50
field found
before ATTRIBUTE1 50->after ATTRIBUTE1 50
field found
before ATTRIBUTE1 50->after ATTRIBUTE1 50
field found
before ATTRIBUTE1 50->after ATTRIBUTE1 50
field found
before ATTRIBUTE1 50->after ATTRIBUTE1 50
field found
before ATTRIBUTE1 50->after ATTRIBUTE1 50
field found
before ATTRIBUTE1 50->after ATTRIBUTE1 50
field found
before ATTRIBUTE1 8->after ATTRIBUTE1 50
field found
before ATTRIBUTE1 50->after ATTRIBUTE1 50
field found
before ATTRIBUTE1 50->after ATTRIBUTE1 50
field found
before ATTRIBUTE1 50->after ATTRIBUTE1 50
field found
before ATTRIBUTE1 8->after ATTRIBUTE1 50
field found
before ATTRIBUTE1 8->after ATTRIBUTE1 50
```

But changes in the layers are not being persisted. What am I doing wrong?

Related:

- [Changing field values with PyQGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/403709/changing-field-values-with-pyqgis)
- [update fields with pyqgis](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/238941/update-fields-with-pyqgis)
- https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/316987/146094